# How to get [qualtrics] to embed correct row of imported data

Tags: survey, piping, qualtrics

I am running a panel survey on Qualtrics and want to embed subjects' responses from the first wave in the second wave (a separate survey, so within-survey piping isn't possible).

What I want to do is have subjects enter their survey ID at the start of the second wave, have Qualtrics look up that survey ID on an imported CSV file, and embed the first-wave responses from the row with the matching survey ID throughout the second wave.

Is this possible? I have several hundred subjects, so manually embedding data for each would be technically possible but very time-consuming.

Comment: Why not just add responses to survey 1 as embedded data fields in your panel, then you can use this data anywhere in the new survey so long as you capture the fields in the beginning.

Comment: This is basically what I'm trying to do. I have been able to import the first wave responses into Qualtrics, but I don't know how get Qualtrics to 1) recognize which row of responses has the survey ID that matches what subjects entered at the beginning of the second wave and 2) populate the embedded data components of the survey with those responses.

At the moment, the Qualtrics preview survey simply skips over questions that have embedded data components in the text, even though they come after the "Set Embedded Data" section.

Comment: Are you sending this survey via the qualtrics mailer? Data will be pulled in automatically if you use unique links for each respondent

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Using an authenticator, I can solicit the survey ID and match it to an uploaded Contact list containing the embedded data values. Loading the embedded data immediately after authentication ensures that all of the piping works properly.